# ARC: Converting a Retained Declared Property with Custom Setter

Tags: objective-c, automatic-ref-counting

I am trying to convert a project to use ARC.

I have a declared property like such:

```
@property (nonatomic, retain, setter=setSomeProperty:) SomeClass * someProperty;
```

A declaration of the setter method in the interface:

```
-(void)setSomeProperty:(SomeClass *)value;
```

And I have an implementation of the setter that looks like this:

```
-(void)setSomeProperty:(SomeClass *)value
{
    if (_value != value)
    {
         [_value release];
         _value = [value retain];
    }

    // Other things...
}
```

I'm getting an error when trying to use the "Convert to Objective-C ARC..." tool:

> error: type of property 'someProperty' does not match type of accessor
>   'setSomeProperty:' [-Werror,3]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Remove the declaration of the `setSomeProperty` method from the interface. The `@property` creates a declaration and the default setter is the same as is declared.

```
-(void)setSomeProperty:(SomeClass *)value;
```

Comment: Ok, but the important part here is the "// Other things..." part of the setter. I want to perform some custom logic when the property is set. So... I need a custom setter... or an alternative.

Comment: Your proposal (to remove "setter=setSomeProperty:") doesn't fix the compile error. The code you suggest still breaks.

Comment: If I remove the declaration from the interface it doesn't show the compiler error... but I guess I'm confused about this because why shouldn't I be able to declare the setter? What if I don't want to use that name? I feel like I'm not even sure that method will be called now.

Comment: OK... here's the deal... remove the declaration of the method from the interface, but it's fine to leave the "setter=..." attribute.

Comment: `@property` creates a declaration and the default setter is the same as you declared.

Comment: Yeah, but only in my example. The key point here was that I needed to remove the declaration of the setter from my interface. If anyone is reading this, that's what they need to do. The "setter=..." and everything else has nothing to do with the solution.

Comment: If you'll strip the answer down to the essentials I'll mark it as the answer. Also, no need to mention the retain / release... that's the point of the conversion tool. It will remove those for us.